# How to say "you brought the weather with you?"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

In English we often say "you brought the weather with you" when someone has come from a place that is famous for bad weather. I've heard Germans say this when speaking English, so I reckon this is also said in German. Would it be

Du hast das Wetter mitgebracht?

I'm only interested in colloquial translations. If it works but sounds weird, then just forget about it.

Comment: [Always!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ag8XcMG1EX4)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it's very similar in (colloquial) German, in various forms, for example:

> Da hast du aber tolles Wetter mitgebracht! *(both serious or sarcastic)*
>
> Habt ihr dieses schlechte Wetter mitgebracht?
>
> Mein Onkel kam heute Mittag am Bahnhof an und hat anscheinend das Wetter aus seiner Heimat mitgebracht.

And last but not least your example (this word order makes more sense in this context):

> Hast du das Wetter mitgebracht?

Answer (score 2):

A literal translation, "Hast du das Wetter mitgebracht?" works to satisfy the minimum requirements.

But in German, it is more common to say something like, "Hast du das *schlechte* Wetter mitgebracht?"

In German, you are more explicit about the "bad" weather because it is not as easily "understood" as it might be in English.